# Please add tag to shopping questions when closing/flagging

Tags: feature-request

This is just a general notice: when you come across a 'shopping' question (plugin, theme, hosting recommendation), as well as closing/flagging the question and leaving a comment, please also add the appropriate tag ([plugin-recommendation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-recommendation), [theme-recommendation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-recommendation), or [hosting-recommendation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting-recommendation)). This helps with organizing questions, and will filter out those off-topic questions for people who are ignoring those tags.

Comment: Just a note to the author of this question: Downvoting doesn't mean that the question is crap or similar. It's just a "I agree/disagree with this idea" vote. Don't take that personal. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure maintaining tags for the questions we *don't* want creates the right signal. Tags are very proactively suggested when asking new question and mere fact of these popping up there might be taken as encouragement.